# Can't access the web interface in Hadoop version 3

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I'm running Ubuntu 18 in a VMware workstation, and have followed these instructions:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-18-04

It works, but I can't access the web interface on localhost port 9870.

It says:

> unable to connect

in Firefox.

I've tried to connect in my navigator to various ports like 5010, it doesn't work.

Hadoop seems to be working and I've formatted the HDFS.

Please help!

Comment: post output of 'jps' command

Comment: it says '9886 Jps'

Comment: how you say hadoop seems to be working?

Comment: type 'bin/hdfs' after going into hadoop folder and post output

Comment: Usage: hdfs [OPTIONS] SUBCOMMAND [SUBCOMMAN OPTIONS] and a lot of lines

Comment: edit question to post updated changes. Hdfs output, new jps output rerun after formatting

Comment: Hello ! I've re installed version 2.5.6 and the jps now says this : 15475 RessourceManager 15635 NodeManager 15950 Jps I still cant access inside firefox

Comment: Oh i just have succeded to connect inside firefox with 127.0.0.1/8088/cluster !! I dont understand why it is this port !! it says 'yarn' but I also need to connect to the hadoop web interface and cant find the port

Comment: According to the above comment, Namenode isn't even running, therefore you obviously can't connect if you had the right port

Comment: Format namenode and restart all services.